# Create variable containing the conditional mean of a group

Tags: qgis, conditional, grouping, mean

I have a table with three columns, the first defining a group (Group), the second a characteristic (Species), and the third a numeric value (Height). I would like to obtain a fourth numeric column in the attribute table containing the mean value of each group for a certain characteristic.

For example, for all values of each group it shall contain the respective group's mean height of animals (no matter the height of other species). If there are no animals the result should be empty/missing.

[image]

I tried the following command without success (only NULL values):

```
New_Var = mean(  "Height" , group_by := "Group", filter := "Species" = "animal" )
```

Comment: The last part is wrong, "animal" should be 'animal' with single quotation marks. Double quotation marks are always interpreted as column names in QGIS.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know. Unfortunately, correcting this doesn't alter the results.

Comment: My bad!  Indeed, eurojam's correction solved the problem, I just commited an error when applying the solution. Thanks, MrXsquared, for pointing out that the command is correct when using single quotation marks!